# PTIJ: Who are the Assistant kings?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I was recently a guest at the home of Reb Yid for Leil Shabbos. He sang a song as follows שלום אליכם מלכי השריס מלכיליון... Sholom Aleichem Malchei HaShoreis Malcheiyelyon...

Who are these assistant kings? (Malchei Hashoreis)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80556/5323

Answer (score 1):

- מלכי-ליון, [King Lion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion_King)
- [King Sporus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporus) was a *שריס*