# PTIJ: Why do we honor sailors every Erev Shabbos

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The famous song Shalom Aleichem (though I am not sure what connection the Yiddish author has with shabbos) starts each verse greeting a group of sailors (Shalom Aleichem malachei) since [מלח means sailor](http://mymemory.translated.net/en/English/Hebrew/sailor). In any case, why are sailors specifically honored for shabbos?

Note that it could not have been the author because the song was written long before he was born.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80550/5323

Answer (score 7):

The sailors are honored as thanks to them we have fish for the Shabbos Seuda.

Answer (score 1):

Oy! You've heard it incorrectly, I'm afraid. The term is *Meluchei Hasheret* - the people that serve salt.

This refers to the special servants that many of the arbbanim had in their home. When they made *Hamotzi*, the servants came with the salt for the bread.

Answer (score 1):

We honour the holy sailors of Beishan, who would not undertake even short sea voyages on Erev Shabbat, for fear of coming to desecrate Shabbat.

[Pesachim 50b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.50b.11?lang=bi):

> בני ביישן נהוג דלא הוו אזלין מצור לצידון במעלי שבתא
>
> The residents of Beishan were accustomed not to travel from Tyre to Sidon on Shabbat eve.